# Regex expression for home address not return false

Tags: php

I'm trying to create an address validation, but separate accoding to street, city and country.

Here's the code,

```
  private function _is_address($value) {
    $reg_ex = '/\d+ [0-9a-zA-Z ]+/';
    if (preg_match($reg_ex, $value)) {
      return $value;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
```

The inputs I tried is

```
Street: 09 Exdodus Road
City: Davao City
Country: Philippines
```

I got false on both City and Country. I new to regular expression, so its a little bit difficult for me to figure out, what wrong.

Anyone has an Idea?

Comment: Hint...  `d+`  :) I'm sure you are testing each address element individually against this regex, send the whole address as 1 string and it should work. If you want to separate them there have to be different conditions for them. City or country names don't require a Number at the begining

Comment: I see, it works, when i tried `/^[0-9a-zA-Z- ]$/`

Comment: https://eval.in/754799

Comment: @sahil nice one .....

Comment: @Fil  If this question is resolved by a couple of comments, chances are this is a low/no value question.  If you had done even a little bit of research on introductory regex, you would have arrived at your solution yourself.  Please delete this question.